# How to backup many large files to single compressed file on S3

Tags: linux, tar, storage, gzip, amazon-s3

I have an application that has many thousands of files totaling over 10TB.

I'd need to backup this data somewhere (probably to AWS S3).

I'd like to:

1. compress data being backed up
2. save the backup as a single file

For example as a gzipped tarfile.

Because of the size, I cannot create the gzipped tarfile locally because it'd be too large.

How can I:

1. Stream all of these folders and files onto AWS S3 as a single compressed file?
2. Stream the compressed file from S3 back onto my disk to the original filesystem layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic piping and `ssh` use case.

```
$ tar zcf - -C /path/to/your/files . | ssh S3_hostname 'cat > yourfile.tar.gz'
```

To decompress:

```
$ ssh S3_hostname 'cat yourfile.tar.gz' | tar zxf - -C /path/to/extract/to
```

The key here is telling `tar` that it should write to or read from `stdout`/`stdin` instead of a file on the local filesystem.  In the case of `tar` creating the archive, the `stdout` from tar is fielded by `ssh` which pipes it to the remote invocation of `cat` running on the S3 host, where the output gets written to file `yourfile.tar.gz`.  In the decompression scenario, `ssh` is again used to invoke `cat` on the remote host to read the file, and that stream becomes the `stdin` stream for a local invocation of `tar` which extracts the archive to the path specified in the `-C` argument.

Comment: This is great, thank you! However how do you open an SSH connection to your S3 bucket? I wasn't aware you could do this and can't seem to find documentation.